# How to communicate to USB-HID device on windows?

Tags: windows, usb, libusb

I am not a Windows expert and have no development experience in windows driver but have doing the same in Linux.

**My system:**
I have a HID device (touch screen) which is recognised by the windows as a digitizer and all works well (needs no additional drivers). The HID uses interface 0 with a interrupt based IN endpoint (as in any HID device) and the touch information are sent on this interface to the Windows. I have another interface 1 with an OUT and IN interrupt endpoint which can send 64 bytes of data. And as all USB devices i have End Point 0 to send Control transfers.

**My problem**
I have to communicate to this device over the interface 0, interface 1 and control endpoint to upgrade the firmware of touch chips and for some diagnostic parameters.
I do all these things with ease using libusb in Linux. But windows I am not able to do any thing. Please also see my effort here [libusb_open returns 'LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED' on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177/libusb-open-returns-libusb-error-not-supported-in-windows-7)

I would like to build a tool with Qt and some USB based driver. Could anybody kindly please suggest me the best interface i can use for USB communication? Is there any way i can use MINGW?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki), its API is compatible to libusb-0.1 in Linux. But you have to install a driver - in your case you probably need the filter version of the driver, to be able to use the HID functionality in your OS as usual. Libusb-win32 ships with a wizard for driver creation, which will generate the `.inf` file for the device.

Driver Installation will be tricky: Users do not get prompted to install a driver for HID compatible devies.