# ST-UTIL & STM32F0DISCOVERY: Failed to find an stlink v1 by VID:PID

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, gdbserver

Apologies for a stupid question, I am fairly new to this field and I am not yet comfortable with all this.

I am trying to use GDB server ST-UTIL tool and GNU ARM compiler with STM32DISCOVERY board [(link)](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF250863), and, so far, I'm having a miserable time.

This is the error I get when I try to run ST-UTIL:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFJlR.png

I didn't manage to find anything useful by googling it. I am using windows 7 x64. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to rebuild my Windows 8.1 x64 system and that meant re-installing everything needed to communicate with applications that use libusb so I have seen this same issue recently.

I prefer OpenOCD as my debug server but the problem resolution is probably the same. You need to use the [zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) utility to install a filter driver so that your libusb programs can see your ST-Link chip. I wrote more about it on my [website](http://www.andybrown.me.uk/wk/2014/09/09/stlinkv2). You may find it useful.

Comment: Nice! I'll try it later when I'm done with work and I'll report back the results. Thanks so much!

Comment: I should also add that the ST-Link on the F0 discovery board is a v2, not a v1. OpenOCD definitely supports the v2, not so sure about "ST-Util"

Comment: Hey,

I managed to find some time today. I looked up and I actually have stm32vldiscovery board, so it should be st-link V1 in the end. I installed the driver via zadig and this is what I get now with openOCD (i just cant make st-util to work): 

[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/JH6Xt8P.png) . Any more hints? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177/libusb-open-returns-libusb-error-not-supported-in-windows-7) help? I'm assuming that you downloaded the OpenOCD binaries from [Freddie Chopin's site](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/4-openocd) because his OpenOCD distro has libusb support compiled into it.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I am not entirely sure what happened between yesterday and today... Today, the board was recognized only as a mass storage device, and simply installing WINUSB driver over it in Zadig did the trick, whereas yesterday I clearly remember there were 2 different entries for the device in Zadig... but my excessive fatigue after work and probably usage of USB3 port might had something to do with it... Thanks very much, the struggle continues!