# libusb can't get device handle

Tags: visual-studio, libusb

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <wtypes.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libusb.h"
#include "resource.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;
    USHORT VendorID = 0x04b4;
    USHORT ProductID = 0x00f3;
    libusb_device_handle * DeviceHandle;

    AllocConsole();

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0)
        return (int)cnt;

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return 1;
        }
        if (desc.idVendor == VendorID &&
            desc.idProduct == ProductID){

            int err = libusb_open(dev,
                &DeviceHandle);
            if (err < 0){
                printf("GetLastError : %d\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
                }
            libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

            libusb_close(DeviceHandle);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. Problem is that I can't get device handle. &DeviceHandle is just a lot of 0 and get last error doesn't give me anything. If it is important I try to take handle to cypress fx3. It compiles and works perfectly until I go to this point. Any thoughts about this problem are welcome.

Comment: What do you get in `err`?

Comment: That's `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED  
Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform.` http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__misc.html#ggab2323aa0f04bc22038e7e1740b2f29efa01b43115484f435627be755d5dc9509b

Comment: Maybe check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177/libusb-open-returns-libusb-error-not-supported-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `libusb_open(dev, &DeviceHandle);` returns `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177/libusb-open-returns-libusb-error-not-supported-on-windows-7) suggests you may be missing the winusb driver.