# node escpos LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes, pos

I am trying to print with thermal printer , i am using node-escpos module to print it is working well with linux but in windows i'm getting error.node escpos  LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

```
Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
    at Device.usb.Device.open (C:\Users\Prashanth\Desktop\pos\node_modules\usb\usb.js:38:7)
    at USB.open (C:\Users\Prashanth\Desktop\pos\node_modules\escpos\adapter\usb.js:107:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Prashanth\Desktop\pos\node_modules\escpos\examples\barcode.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

I have tried On Windows, Use Zadig to install the WinUSB driver for your USB device.but its not showing any thing as they mention  zadig site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libusb\_open returns 'LIBUSB\_ERROR\_NOT\_SUPPORTED' on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350177/libusb-open-returns-libusb-error-not-supported-on-windows-7)

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I have seen that one but when i'm trying to install its not showing anything to install like what they have metion

Answer (score 0):

Used zadig to make this work. If this is still an open thread you can let me know. But major drawback of this is on every Windows OS you have to install zadig and configure USB properties which is going to be real pain and not a scalable option at all.

Comment: I'm facing this issue, could you explain what configurations you made to USB properties in order to make it work, thanks.

Comment: If you have windows 8.1 or windows 10 - this link would help in setting up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zRMv80y6PY
If you have windows 7 you need to reboot and follow the same steps

Answer (score 0):

finally i was solved with zadig in windows, same like info in [repo](https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/tree/v3/packages/usb)

the step in the windows case:

1. download [zadig](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libwdi/files/zadig/zadig_v2.0.1.160.7z/download)
2. open zadig > options > list All Devices
3. in my case select "micro-printer" (which one printer in ur usb)
4. install driver and works well in code *but in windows can't print manually